# How to optimize my maxsum code and improve time complexity?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am working on HackerRank problem(maximum-subarray-sum).

[maximum subarray sum problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximum-subarray-sum/problem)

Given an element array of integers a and an integer m determine the maximum value of the sum of any of its subarrays modulo m.

[image]

My code works fine, but should be optimized for larger sets.

```
b=[]
def maximumSum(a, m):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a)):
            if j>=i:
                subarray = a[i:j+1]
                b.append(subarray)

    return max([sum(i)%m for i in b])
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quadratic time, just like the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76550282/12671057) from prhmma, but simpler and faster. I just accumulate the array suffixes. Benchmark with several array lengths:

```
array length: 100
  0.64 ± 0.01 ms  Kelly
  1.71 ± 0.00 ms  prhmma
  4.55 ± 0.06 ms  original

array length: 500
 15.63 ± 0.02 ms  Kelly
 45.19 ± 0.20 ms  prhmma
341.87 ± 1.06 ms  original

array length: 1000
 62.12 ± 0.27 ms  Kelly
180.37 ± 0.23 ms  prhmma
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRLbtswEN3rFASKwGSsGrLdFK0AZdNll12qgkFZVExXpASSam0EOVSv0Iu5w48sKUGCaGXO9817M@7O5tDK7ZdOXS4Vq9F31jRnTGMkSBoh@CjKEM3Twj1KeCTu158DbxiiPsZ@@uqyX90qdEJcTiOGKKzREp0IukFi5uM1uO9ROc8Y2uqrla66tsMJcQbFTK8kKqMosvBbxR@4pM10gjLLPXoLiltQisoHhhsmMSUknYE@vuEPII/3GX@JUfclVYqeHV08PS7Xxcs5VrTrmKzwEDybQdATznUvMCc3YgRbFiQM16mDEHQ6WqdYzU87SIK2eVKgW@RROy8UDC4vzL5Xiklztb2LlHkSnj6XdtJiLuSICFyQMIl/td@YM208orfEhFc8b0Ci18TjgG4To9fLv9FikpEfC/Tx2VBLoN/OHJqP6vkho7qXe7vnwy7G/qjioB8EqFYgwwXjBnHRtcqEl/doQw3XhkOR4BWMyhjsFfsdBRNMWbXQ7QP61gLDeyOZ1pElYTeSsJ3csE9Y7Q8t3zONfcA6ub39SmL0K9sk4aAsG87sXuzUQW0wuaFgw/z2heXj0uB68XgNelqQq8a1heGz1mkx8q6Y7htXcVLKgdSa2cGCPwu97Yg/OsYqdwKGaYOBC1f4egQWx@Kn9PcHkj@YQ7qIkfTFLbdWj8c6RXnxDNyTC7GlLe0a15MVMTYrN3BUa7Z1ecbmaeCfVdiVzeuC5OldUUzmc@sAtFjVsAGUn1eb@gn9@4senYTO9snZhEaL8Swmym3uJjjeIZ8ceZwL@FKO@QlYJfzy4YaKsqLpIAzw14uSqWxN5hlh7uG/zJBoLnrgxzUDbOycOWonA3nFBsJBzdVuJ6lgux3UchKvk2QQ2RvunhsgYrDYBSOXy38)):

```
def Kelly(a, m):
    a = a[:]
    b = 0
    while a:
        s = 0
        for x in a:
            s = (s + x) % m
            if s > b:
                b = s
        a.pop(0)
    return b


def original(a, m):
    b=[]
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a)):
            if j>=i:
                subarray = a[i:j+1]
                b.append(subarray)
    return max([sum(i)%m for i in b])


def prhmma(a, m):
    prefix_sum = [0] * len(a)
    max_sum = 0
    current_sum = 0

    for i in range(len(a)):
        current_sum = (current_sum + a[i]) % m
        prefix_sum[i] = current_sum

    for i in range(len(prefix_sum)):
        max_sum = max(max_sum, prefix_sum[i])

        for j in range(i + 2, len(prefix_sum)):
            max_sum = max(max_sum, (prefix_sum[j] - prefix_sum[i] + m) % m)

    return max_sum


funcs = original, Kelly, prhmma

from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
import random

# Correctness
for _ in range(3):
    a = random.choices(range(10**9), k=200)
    m = 10**9
    expect = funcs[0](a, m)
    print(f'{expect = }')
    for f in funcs[1:]:
        result = f(a, m)
        assert result == expect

# Speed
def test(n, funcs):
    print('\narray length:', n)
    times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
    def stats(f):
        ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
        return f'{mean(ts):6.2f} ± {stdev(ts):4.2f} ms '

    for _ in range(25):
        a = random.choices(range(10**9), k=n)
        m = 10**9
        for f in funcs:
            t = timeit(lambda: f(a, m), number=1)
            times[f].append(t)

    for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
        print(stats(f), f.__name__)

test(100, funcs)
test(500, funcs)
test(1000, funcs[1:])
```

Probably it can be done in sub-quadratic time, but you accepted quadratic time already, and the testing/benchmark code can still be useful when someone comes up with something faster.

Comment: I am not sure that you have created all subarrays,can you confirm this?

Comment: I added image which clarifies this.

Comment: @MikiBelavista My solution does all.

Comment: @MikiBelavista For the image's example array 123, my solution first computes the sums of the subarrays 1, 12 and 123. Then it pops the 1 and computes the sums of the subarrays 2 and 23. Then it pops the 2 and computes the sum of the subarray 3.